# Notepad++ Merge 10+ lines into 1 line

Tags: notepad++, regex, merge, join

I'm trying to use Notepad++ to merge multiple lines into one. The problem I'm facing is when trying this code, I get this result:

```
Date/Time:
Sequence:
Event:
Category:
Priority:
Attention:
Alert:
Visibility:
Description:
Codes:
Type:
Location:
Logged by:
```

Find: `(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)`

Replace with:
`\1\t\2\t\3\t\4\t\5\t\6\t\7\t\8\t\9\t\10\t\11\t\12\t\13\t`

Result:
`Date/Time: Sequence:   Event:  Category:   Priority:   Attention:  Alert:  Visibility: Description:    Date/Time:0 Date/Time:1 Date/Time:2 Date/Time:3`

Can anyone assist with a easier or shorter way? I can't highlight the text and select to Join Lines. The document has thousands of these results and I'm trying to streamline. It's always a set of 13.

Comment: Have you tried `TextFX` Plugin in Notepad++, It provides a menu option `TextFX>TextFX Edit>Unwrap Text` which does what you require ? Also you could have just replaced `\r\n` with `\t` in extended search mode

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Change your replace to use braced numbers:

**Edit**: Corrected replacement string

<strike>\g{1}\t\g{2}\t\g{3}\t\g{4}\t\g{5}\t\g{6}\t\g{7}\t\g{8}\t\g{9}\t\g{10}\t\g{11}\t\g{12}\t\g{13}\t</strike>

```
${1}\t${2}\t${3}\t${4}\t${5}\t${6}\t${7}\t${8}\t${9}\t${10}\t${11}\t${12}\t${13}
```

Option 2: Your match string to include named groups:

```
(?<a>.+)\r\n(?<b>.+)\r\n(?<c>.+)\r\n(?<d>.+)\r\n(?<e>.+)\r\n(?<f>.+)\r\n(?<g>.+)\r\n(?<h>.+)\r\n(?<i>.+)\r\n(?<j>.+)\r\n(?<k>.+)\r\n(?<l>.+)\r\n(?<m>.+)
```

AND, change the replace string to use those groups:

**Edit**: Corrected replacement string

<strike>\g{a}\t\g{b}\t\g{c}\t\g{d}\t\g{e}\t\g{f}\t\g{g}\t\g{h}\t\g{i}\t\g{j}\t\g{k}\t\g{l}\t\g{m}</strike>

```
$+{a}\t$+{b}\t$+{c}\t$+{d}\t$+{e}\t$+{f}\t$+{g}\t$+{h}\t$+{i}\t$+{j}\t$+{k}\t$+{l}\t$+{m}
```

Your choice, although option 1 is less work, option 2 can come in handy as well.

**New Note**: The names in option 2, `<a>` and `{a}` are not limited to one character. They can be any 'name' type string you want, as long as it is in the normal range of letters, number, and underscores. Not sure if other special characters, including spaces, are valid. Avoiding them is wisest, just in case.

Comment: Hi Gypsy, using option 1 I got:

g{1} g{2} g{3} g{4} g{5} g{6} g{7} g{8} g{9} g{10} g{11} g{12} g{13}

And using option 2, I got:

g{a} g{b} g{c} g{d} g{e} g{f} g{g} g{h} g{i} g{j} g{k} g{l} g{m}

Comment: Scrap that, using option 1 nothing happened

And using option 2, I got:

g{a} g{b} g{c} g{d} g{e} g{f} g{g} g{h} g{i} g{j} g{k} g{l} g{m}

Comment: My bad. The `\g{12}` and `\g{name}` versions are for backreferences in the search itself. Here are the corrected versions: 1) Instead of `\g{12}` use `${12}`. So it's `${1}\t${2}\t${3}\t${4}\t${5}\t${6}\t${7}\t${8}\t${9}\t${10}\t${11}\t${12}\t${13}`. 2) Instead of `\g{a}` use `$+{a}`, so it's `$+{a}\t$+{b}\t$+{c}\t$+{d}\t$+{e}\t$+{f}\t$+{g}\t$+{h}\t$+{i}\t$+{j}\t$+{k}\t$+{l}\t$+{m}`. Notice that in both versions there is no `\` before the `$`. For version 2 the search string stays the same. BTW the `(?<a>...` is not limited to 1 character. It can be `(?<my_flag_15>...`, for example.

Comment: @pau13z. Answer updated with the corrected replacement strings. Sorry for that.

Comment: Legend! Option 1 worked for me :) Cheers mate

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1

Search → Replace...

- Find what: \r\n
- Replace with: \t
- Wrap around: Checked
- Search mode: Regular expression

### Method 2

Edit → Blank Operations → EOL to Space

Answer (score 0):

If all set of 13 lines begin with `Date/Time:`, you could do this. It will replace all linebreaks that are not followed by `Date/Time` with a tabulation:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!Date/Time:)`
- Replace with: `\t`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R              : any kind of linebreak
(?!             : start negative lookahead, make sure we don't have after
  Date/Time:    : literally
)               : end lookahead
```

**Result for 3 sets of lines:**

```
Date/Time:  Sequence:   Event:  Category:   Priority:   Attention:  Alert:  Visibility: Description:    Codes:  Type:   Location:   Logged by:
Date/Time:  Sequence:   Event:  Category:   Priority:   Attention:  Alert:  Visibility: Description:    Codes:  Type:   Location:   Logged by:
Date/Time:  Sequence:   Event:  Category:   Priority:   Attention:  Alert:  Visibility: Description:    Codes:  Type:   Location:   Logged by:
```